# Wagtail ModelAdmin cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other

Tags: wagtail, modeladmin

In Django you can add a `clean` method to a form to validate fields that depend on each other:

```
def clean_recipients(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['recipients']
    if "fred@example.com" not in data:
        raise ValidationError("You have forgotten about Fred!")

    # Always return a value to use as the new cleaned data, even if
    # this method didn't change it.
    return data
```

How can I add a custom form with a clean method to [Wagtail ModelAdmin](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html)?

Wagtail has the `panels` concept and dynamically builds the form. I can't find anything about overriding the form. There is information about customising the create and update views. Custom views seem a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 4):

I got an answer via the Wagtail Slack form @CynthiaKiser.

The `base_form_class` lets you set a `WagtailAdminModelForm` on the model.

```
from wagtail.admin.forms import WagtailAdminModelForm

class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    base_form_class = FooForm


class FooForm(WagtailAdminModelForm):  # For pages use WagtailAdminPageForm
    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['recipients']
        if "fred@example.com" not in data:
            raise ValidationError("You have forgotten about Fred!")
        return data
```

All of the CRUD forms you encounter in Wagtail are just Django ModelForm instances underneath, so [these Django docs are relevant](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) (thanks @ababic)

An alternative to `base_form_class` is to specify a clean method on the model. It will be called by any form.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        if "fred@example.com" not in self.recipients:
            raise ValidationError(
                {'recipients': _("You have forgotten about Fred!")}
            )
```

Comment: With noting that all of the CRUD forms you encounter in Wagtail are just Django ModelForm instances underneath, so these Django docs are relevant: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

Comment: Just a note here because this tripped me up for a bit: you should use the appropriate Wagtail base form for the model you're working with. If you're inheriting from `Page` instead of `models.Model` you'd import `WagtailAdminPageForm` instead of `WagtailAdminModelForm`